# MS's Apr 10 update sends Server 2008 R2 to recovery mode

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, server-crashes

Just applied the April 10, 2018 MS patches to a pair of Windows 2008 R2 servers running under VMWare Workstation 7.1.6 build-744570. Host is a Dell Precision 4800, 32GB, i74800MQ CPU with Win7 pro.  Both server instances bluescreen when starting: "STOP: 0x0000007E" then reboot into the recovery console.  [Link to screenshot on IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHr4u.jpg). Options in recovery mode are:

- System Image Recovery (not an option - I don't have any)
- Windows Memory Diagnostic
- Command Prompt

Rebooting the VM brings me right back to the recovery mode.  I *think* the KB notes for [KB4093118](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093118/windows-7-update-kb4093118) and [KB4093108](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093108/windows-7-update-kb4093108) indicate possible stop problems: "**Stop error on PCs that don't support SIMD or SSE2**".  I don't know how to verify those might be my problem.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your VMWare Workstation, we had our ESXI 4.1 environment have this issue this morning, migrating the VMs to a ESXI 5.5 host resolved the issue.